# How to transfer diff between two different file formats?

Tags: patch, diff

I often find it convenient to edit a document in one file format while storing it in another format. For example, a document can be written down in markdown, converted to a word file and edited there. And I am hoping to extract the edits and applied them back to original markdown file.

So, I would have `A.md`, converted to `A.docx` (e.g. using `pandoc`), edited to `B.docx`, and somehow apply the change set between `A.docx` and `B.docx` to `A.md`.

My question is:

*Is there a reliable/automatic way to transfer the edits in word (text edits) back to the text-based files?*

Of course, I can just convert `B.docx` back to a markdown `B.md` and overwrite `A.md` with `B.md`. But the conversion process often introduces irreversible changes so that the loop `A.md` => `A.docx` => `A2.md` will produce a different `A2.md` than the original markdown file `A.md`.  Some effects will be added/lost (due to different newlines, fonts, formatting etc.). And I'd like to avoid such loss, and keep the final document as close to the original file `A.md` as possible.

Would it be possible to use `diff`/`patch` to do the following conversions in bash scripts:

1. `A.md` => `A.docx` => `A2.md`
2. `A.docx` => (edits) `B.docx`
3. `B.docx` => `B.md`
4. `diff B.md A2.md` somehow to get a **portable** patch
5. apply the patch file on `A.md` (**instead of** `A2.md`)

I have limited experience in using `git diff`, but not much with directly using `diff/patch`. And I was wondering if someone can help explain the command sequence needed for such "transfer" of differences.

Comment: Why don't you edit `A.md` directly ? There are [markdown editors available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189934/is-there-a-markdown-rich-text-editor).

Comment: @pLumo `Why don't you edit A.md directly ?`. I work with others who might use a different file format/editor.

Comment: You should agree with the others for one file format ;-) I guess that is not possible what you want.

Comment: @pLumo Yeah, in an ideal world.

Comment: Or use an online editor where you can work together.

Comment: Sounds and looks too complicated. As an alternative see https://askubuntu.com/a/1365833/66509 for RMarkdown + bookdown workflow. It works great with Git and plain RMarkdown files.

Answer (score 1):

The bash syntax for what you ask (steps 4,5) is:

```
diff B.md A2.md > patch.data 
patch A.md patch.data
```

I think you may have the files reversed in the **diff**?  And keep in mind **patch** over-writes A.md so make a copy if you need the original.

In any case, I am skeptical you will be successful with this approach.

To my mind, the Word editor introduces too much non-determinism for any automated conversion to be considered "reliable".  Even if you get a script working, you could wind up having to repair it with every update of your Word editor.

Comment: I tried this a bit, and it seems that diff/patch relies on the newlines to work. And conversion from/to word does introduce some unpredictable changes in new lines, which makes the patch unusable.   But thanks for the help anyways.